# $f_n(ab) = f_n(a)f_n(b) + f_n(a-1)f_n(b-1) + f_n(a-2)f_n(b-2)+ ...+f_n(a-n)f_n(b-n)$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients, functional-equations

I was toying around when I noticed for $a,b > 0$:

$$f(ab) = f(a)f(b) + f(a-1)f(b-1)$$

is satisfied by $f(n) = T_n$ ; the triangular numbers $n(n+1)/2$.

This equation is not an addition formula, not an abel function nor a fibonacci or Somos type recursion.
So I liked that.

So I was wondering about similar equations like

$$f_n(ab) = f_n(a)f_n(b) + f_n(a-1)f_n(b-1) + f_n(a-2)f_n(b-2) + ...+f_n(a-n)f_n(b-n)$$

OR

$$f_W(ab) = f_W(a)f_W(b) + f_W(a-1)f_W(b-1) + f_W(a-2)f_W(b-2) + ...+f_W(0)f_W(0)$$

Can they be understood by the binomium of newton ?

Are they related to the rising factorial ?

The equations look familiar.

I assume they are all polynomials.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Is it helpful to put $a=b$ ? My intuition says yes but ...
So we get at stuff like $f(x^2) = f(x)^2 + f(x-1)^2 + f(x-2)^2$ maybe and somehow find that helpful.

Comment: I am aware of the trivial $f_n(ab) = 0$ as solution ofcourse.

Comment: Are these equations even consistant ? I did not find solutions...